# Updating multiple data entries in SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, loops, sql-update, checkboxlist

I'm getting a list of datetimes and storing them in a checkboxlist with this bit of code:

```
    <anthem:CheckBox ID="chkAll" runat="server" OnCheckedchanged="chkAll_CheckedChanged" Text="Select/Deselect All" AutoPostBack="true"
        style="margin-left: 128px" >
    </anthem:CheckBox>
    <anthem:CheckBoxList ID="CheckOpenTimesheets"  runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="checkbox_Selected" AutoPostBack="true"
        style="margin-left: 128px" >
    </anthem:CheckBoxList>
```

Here's the relevant code behind:

```
            List<ListItem> toBeRemoved = new List<ListItem>();

            for (int i = 1; i < CheckOpenTimesheets.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                toBeRemoved.Add(CheckOpenTimesheets.Items[i]);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < toBeRemoved.Count; i++)
            {
                CheckOpenTimesheets.Items.Remove(toBeRemoved[i]);
            }

            String sql = "SELECT StartDate FROM Periods WHERE User_ID = @userid AND (PeriodStatus_ID = 1 OR PeriodStatus_ID = 2) ORDER BY StartDate DESC";
            command.CommandText = sql;
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("userid", ddlActingAs.SelectedValue.ToString()));

            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {

                ListItem item = new ListItem();
                item.Text += reader.GetDateTime(0).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + " is open";
                item.Value = reader["StartDate"].ToString();

                CheckOpenTimesheets.Items.Add(item);

            }
            CheckOpenTimesheets.UpdateAfterCallBack = true;

            reader.Close();

//The functions below are for selecting/deselecting the items in the checklistbox
protected void chkAll_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ListItem item in CheckOpenTimesheets.Items)
    {
        item.Selected = chkAll.Checked;
    }
}

protected void checkbox_Selected(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    chkAll.CheckedChanged -= chkAll_CheckedChanged;

    CheckBoxList checkOpenTimesheets = (CheckBoxList)sender;
    if (allItemsCheckedInCheckBoxList(checkOpenTimesheets))
    {
        chkAll.Checked = true;
    }
    else if (allItemsUnCheckedInCheckBoxList(checkOpenTimesheets))
    {
        chkAll.Checked = false;
    }

    chkAll.CheckedChanged += chkAll_CheckedChanged;
}

private bool allItemsCheckedInCheckBoxList(CheckBoxList checkBoxList)
{
    bool allItemsChecked = true;

    foreach (ListItem item in checkBoxList.Items)
    {
        allItemsChecked = item.Selected;

        if (!allItemsChecked)
            break;
    }

    return allItemsChecked;
}

private bool allItemsUnCheckedInCheckBoxList(CheckBoxList checkBoxList)
{
    bool allItemsUnChecked = false;

    foreach (ListItem item in checkBoxList.Items)
    {
        allItemsUnChecked = item.Selected;

        if (allItemsUnChecked)
            break;
    }

    return allItemsUnChecked;
}
```

What I'm trying to do is, when a button I have on the page is clicked, it will loop through the checkboxlist, and every item that is checked, will update the PeriodStatus_ID to 5 for each of those items in the SQL table.

The function for the button click is here (not sure how to go about this):

```
protected void SubmitAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ListItem item in CheckOpenTimesheets.Items)
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        command.Connection = gConn;
        if (item.Selected == true)
        {
            String sql = "UPDATE Periods SET PeriodStatus_ID=5 WHERE User_ID = @userid AND StartDate = @startdate";
            command.CommandText = sql;
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("userid", ddlActingAs.SelectedValue.ToString()));
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("startdate", item.Value));
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas on achieving this would be great, thanks in advance.

Comment: You seem to be mixing sql parameters and c# objects. The parameter value would come from CheckOpenTimesheets[i].Value. In your string it would probably be simple @startdate.

Comment: woops, didn't mean to do that. Updated my post. Thanks!

Comment: That now looks correct. Is there still a problem?

Comment: Yes, which execution do I use? I thought it would be command.ExecuteNonQuery(), but that doesn't seem to be right. I know it's not .read. All the examples I've seen tend to use the nonquery execution though.

Comment: Yes ExecuteNonQuery. Why does that not seem right?

Comment: Nevermind, seems to be an issue with one of my parameters not being assigned correctly in a different part of the code. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You updated your code, so I updated mine, but I changed my mind about how you want to structure it. You've also left out the `ExecuteNonQuery` statement, which is [the way](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx) to send an `Update` command.

```
protected void SubmitAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

     SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
     command.Connection = gConn;
     String sql = "UPDATE Periods SET PeriodStatus_ID=5 WHERE User_ID = @userid AND StartDate = @startdate";
     command.CommandText = sql;
     command.Parameters.Add("userid");
     command.Parameters.Add("startdate");

    for (int i = 0; i < CheckOpenTimesheets.Items.Count; i++)
    {

     if (item.Selected == true)
     {
        command.Parameters("userid").Value = ddlActingAs.SelectedValue.ToString();
        command.Parameters("startdate").Value = item.Value;

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I was given some errors and I thought it was related to the .executenonquery part but it's not.